# Which terminal encodings are default on Linux, and which are most common?

Tags: character-encoding

I need to make a decision regarding whether a complicated commercial program that I work on should assume a particular terminal encoding for Linux, or instead read it from the terminal (and if so, how).

It's pretty easy to guess which system and terminal encodings are most common on Windows. We can assume that most users configure these through the Control Panel, and that, for instance, their terminal encoding, which is usually non-Unicode, can be easily predicted from the standard configuration for that language/country. (For instance, on a US English machine, it will be OEM-437, while on a Russian machine, it will be OEM-866.)

But it's not clear to me how most users configure their system and terminal encodings on Linux. The savvy ones who often need to use non-ASCII characters probably use a UTF-8 encoding. But what proportion of Linux users fall into that category?

Nor is it clear which method most users use to configure their locale: changing the LANG environment variable, or something else.

A related question would be how Linux configures these by default. My own Linux machine at work (actually a virtual Debian 5 machine that runs via VMWare Player on my Windows machine) is set up by default to use a US-ASCII terminal encoding. However, I'm not sure whether that was set up by administrators at my workplace or that's the setting out of the box.

Please understand that I'm not looking for answers to "Which encoding do you personally use?" but rather some means by which I could figure out the distribution of encodings that Linux users are likely to be using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The oldest character encoding used in consoles like [VT52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT52) was [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

That basic decision has been carried over for many years. Most consoles use ASCII as the most basic character set as defined by ANSI. The next set of encodings (in the west) are the ISO-8859 sets (from 1 to 15). One for each language (language group). Being the most common the ISO-8859-1 (English), and the other in proportion to the corresponding language in use.

Then, the most general list of world characters is Unicode, which, in Linux, is usually encoded in UTF-8.

It is that encoding the most common for present day terminals and programs in Linux.

---

From more general to particular settings:

## OS

The default in [debian since Etch](https://wiki.debian.org/UTF-8) on `Apr 8th 2007` (13 years ago) has been utf-8.

> Note : Fresh Debian/Etch installation have UTF8 enabled by default.

And confirmed on [the release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/etch/i386/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html):

> The default encoding for new Debian GNU/Linux installations is UTF-8. A number of applications will also be set up to use UTF-8 by default.

What that means is that Debian (and Ubuntu, Mint, and many other) are utf-8 **capable** by default.

## locale

Which encoding (and country) is actually chosen by the user with the command `dpkg-reconfigure locales` is left to user preferences.

That configure the actual particular setting for the computer `locale` command.

All of the `LC_*` "environment variables" have specific effects on each of country/language sections (parts) as [defined by the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html).

## tty

But the above are just "general" settings. A particular terminal may (or may not) match it. Well, in general, the usual encoding for most terminals today is utf8.

The encoding for a particular terminal (tty) may be found if set to utf8 with:

```
$ stty -a | grep -o '.iutf8'
 iutf8
```

That is, no `-` before the result printed.

## terminal

But the `terminal` (GUI window) inside which the tty terminal is (usually) running also has its own locale setting. If the [settings are sane](https://askubuntu.com/a/640071/772601), probably:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
```

Will have the correct answer.

But that is just a quick and very shallow look at all the i18n settings of linux/unix.

Take away: Probably, assuming Linux is using utf8 is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a similar heuristic you are using with Windows users, but via the LANG environmental variable.  For example, on my system:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Here, the code is saying I am using the English language, but with UTF-8 encoding of filenames and files.

As a general rule, Linux users using UTF-8 will have "UTF-8" at the end of their LANG environmental variable.

Answer (score 1):

Modern Linux installations (for at least some 5 years, probably longer) use UTF-8. How that is handled by setting the environment values `LC_CTYPE`, `LANG`, and `LANGUAGE`. See for example the discussions [here](http://01101001.net/i18n.php) or [here](http://eyegene.ophthy.med.umich.edu/unicode) (Unicode centered).

Answer (score 1):

For reasonably modern Linux/Unix systems, you shouldn't need to worry about terminal encoding. Just use `getwchar` or `fgetws` to read from `stdin` (or the terminal). [Note 1]

As `man getwchar` says, in the `Notes` section:

> It  is  reasonable  to  expect  that getwchar() will actually read a multibyte sequence from standard input and then convert it to a wide character.

There is a similar note in `man fgetws`.

With Linux, it is also reasonable to expect the encoding of `wchar_t` to be unicode, regardless of locale. The `C99` standard allows the implementation to define the macro `__STDC_ISO_10646__` to indicate that `wchar_t` values correspond to Unicode code points [Note 2], so you can insert a compile-time check for this expectation, which should succeed on modern Linux installs with standard toolchains. It's likely to succeed on modern Unix systems as well, although there is no guarantee.

---

**Notes:**

[1]  You do need to initialize the locale by calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` once at the beginning of program execution. See `man setlocale`.

[2] The value of `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is a date (in format `yyyymmL`) corresponding to the date of the applicable version of the Unicode standard. The precise wording from the standard (draft) is:

> The following macro names are conditionally defined by the implementation:
>
> `__STDC_ISO_10646__` An integer constant of the form `yyyymmL` (for example,
>   `199712L`). If this symbol is defined, then every character in the Unicode
>   required set, when stored in an object of type `wchar_t`, has the same
>   value as the short identifier of that character. The Unicode required set
>   consists of all the characters that are defined by ISO/IEC 10646, along with
>   all amendments and technical corrigenda, as of the specified year and
>   month. If some other encoding is used, the macro shall not be defined and
>   the actual encoding used is implementation-defined.

Comment: Trivia: the date of the macro actually corresponds to the ISO-10646 standard, 199712L corresponds to a non-compatible change, where Korean hangul was moved from some block to another (the "Korean mess", alluded to in the UTF-8 RFC).

Comment: _"it is also reasonable to expect the encoding of wchar_t to be unicode"_ - Unicode is not an encoding, it's the thing being encoded. Do you mean `UTF-16-be`, `UTF-16-le`, `UCS-2`, ...

Comment: @Eric: "Unicode provides a unique number for every character." ([What is Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html)). It is an encoding and the standard quote in my answer uses precisely that word. And here's another one, the [first answer in the Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html): "Unicode is the universal character *encoding*, maintained by the Unicode Consortium." In other words, Unicode encodes every (well, many) characters into a Unicode codepoint...

Comment: UTF-16 is a "Unicode Encoding *Form*" (Section 3.9) which represents each Unicode codepoint as a series of possibly smaller numbers. UTF-16BE is one of the "Encoding *Schemes*" (Section 3.10) used to turn a UTF-16 sequence into a series of bytes for the purposes of interchange between applications. These distinctions involve a lot of hair-splitting, but the precise language can be useful and is described at length in the Unicode book, which is freely available online...

Comment: C definitely confuses the issue; in the ideal, `wchar_t` would just be a number (however numbers might be represented inside the host platform) which is the Unicode codepoint for the character. If `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is set, it is. Otherwise, it might not be and then you have to dig into the documentation for your implementation to see how Unicode codepoints are transformed (or not) into `wchar_t` values.

Comment: So "unicode" is effectively synonymous with UCS-32?

Comment: @eric: there never was a UCS-32; you might be thinking of UCS-4, a term which is no longer used. ISO-10646 defines UCS-4 as the UTF-32 encoding form, which represents Unicode code points in 32-bit binary numbers. Unicode is just abstract mapping (ir encoding) of characters to numbers, without regard to the representation of the numbers. Hiwever, since the range of possible Unicode values is [0, 0x10FFFF], all Unicode  codepoints can be represented in 32 bits by zero extending. In that sense, yes, there is a correspondence.